# javascript putting multiple distinct id into array

Tags: javascript

I have a table

```
<table id='mytable'>
<tr>
  <th> Cars </th>
  <th> Food </th>
  <th> clothes</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td> yes </td>
  <td> jeans </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td> yes </td>
  <td> jeans </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 84 </td>
  <td> no </td>
  <td> shirt </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 4984 </td>
  <td> yes </td>
  <td> hat </td>
</tr>
```

I have a javascript function that takes the first td and get the value, but it only takes the first value in this case 1. I want to take all of the first columns distinct values and store it in an array. so the end result should be

```
$firstColumnArray = [1,84, 4984]
```

My function looks like

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$one = document.getElementById("table");
$two = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text()
alert($two);
});
```

How can i loop though the entire contents of the tables first row and store it in a variable?

Comment: You want to iterate all the td elements of the first row? Or iterate all the rows and grab the value of the first column? Because your end result example would indicate you want to do the latter. Since you are using JQuery, I would suggest using .each() to iterate each row, then do your find("td").eq(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over all rows

```
let res = [];
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).find('td:first').length) return;
    var customerId = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();   
    res.push(customerId); 
});
```

then filter out duplicates.

```
let finalRes = res.filter( function (value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this selector** `"tr > td:first-child"`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var values = []; 
  $('#mytable').find("tr > td:first-child").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).html().trim();
    if (!values.includes(value)) 
      values.push(value);      
  });
  
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='mytable'>
  <tr>
    <th> Cars </th>
    <th> Food </th>
    <th> clothes</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> yes </td>
    <td> jeans </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> yes </td>
    <td> jeans </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 84 </td>
    <td> no </td>
    <td> shirt </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 4984 </td>
    <td> yes </td>
    <td> hat </td>
  </tr>
  I have a javascript function that takes the first td and get the value, but it only takes the first value in this case 1. I want to take all of the first columns distinct values and store it in an array. so the end result should be
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate them and exclude the property using the includes array method..

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var result = [];
  $('table tr').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).find('td:first').length) return;
    var text = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    if(!result.includes(text)){
      result.push(text);
    }
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='mytable'>
<tr>
  <th> Cars </th>
  <th> Food </th>
  <th> clothes</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td> yes </td>
  <td> jeans </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td> yes </td>
  <td> jeans </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 84 </td>
  <td> no </td>
  <td> shirt </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 84 </td>
  <td> no </td>
  <td> shirt </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 4984 </td>
  <td> yes </td>
  <td> hat </td>
</tr>
</table>
```